Nvidia Driver Installation Error Using Terminal
The Following Error Occured While Installing Nvidia Driver :
phantom@PhantomBox:~$ sudo apt install nvidia-driver-390
[sudo] password for phantom:     
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
nvidia-driver-390 is already the newest version (390.157-0ubuntu0.22.04.2).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Setting up nvidia-dkms-390 (390.157-0ubuntu0.22.04.2) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
INFO:Enable nvidia
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/dell_latitude
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/lenovo_thinkpad
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/put_your_quirks_here
Removing old nvidia-390.157 DKMS files...
Deleting module nvidia-390.157 completely from the DKMS tree.
Loading new nvidia-390.157 DKMS files...
Building for 6.8.0-40-generic
Building for architecture x86_64
Building initial module for 6.8.0-40-generic
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 6.8.0-40-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/390.157/build/make.log for more information.
dpkg: error processing package nvidia-dkms-390 (--configure):
 installed nvidia-dkms-390 package post-installation script subprocess returned 
error exit status 10
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of nvidia-driver-390:
 nvidia-driver-390 depends on nvidia-dkms-390 (<= 390.157-1); however:
  Package nvidia-dkms-390 is not configured yet.
 nvidia-driver-390 depends on nvidia-dkms-390 (>= 390.157); however:
  Package nvidia-dkms-390 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package nvidia-driver-390 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.140ubuntu13.4) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-6.8.0-40-generic
Errors were encountered while processing:
 nvidia-dkms-390
 nvidia-driver-390
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
phantom@PhantomBox:~$


Did you consult /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/390.157/build/make.log as suggested?

See launchpad bugs https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gcc-defaults/+bug/2051457 and https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers-390/+bug/2028165 for some ideas on handling a new compiler for the old Nvidia drivers. Are you using the graphics-drivers PPA? Might have to use an older kernel than 6.8.

This question is similar to: Unable to install nvidia-driver-495 and nvidia-dkms-495. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

This solution helped me. It requires patching of the driver downloaded manually from nvidia website. It does install after that and shows with nvidia-smi command.
p.s.
However in my case, it still threw errors (like "stack smashing") so I had to to uninstall it.
